# The type 'projectname.Repositories.IRepository' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm an intern at a company, and my assignment is to provide them with a working web portal. Since I'm an intern my skillset isn't that advanced yet, so they hired a senior developer that's gonna work with us. He set up our project structure etc... He told us to work with AutoFac for DI but I'm not familiar at all with this. This guy is on vacation now so he can't really help us atm.

When using Autofac I get this error and I don't know how to fix it..

> The type 'projectnamespace.Repositories.IRepository' could not be
>   found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType,
>   MyAssembly".
>   [image]

My Global.asax.cs

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //register types from configuration
        builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader());
        // Register your MVC controllers.
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Web.config

```xml
<autofac>
  <components>
    <component
      type="projectnamespace.Repositories.OrderRepository, projectnamespace"
      service="projectnamespace.Repositories.IRepository" />
  </components>
</autofac>
```

IRepository.cs

```
public interface IRepository
{
    string FetchAll();
}
```

OrderRepository.cs

```
public class OrderRepository : IRepository
{
    public string FetchAll()
    {
        return "return something";
    }
}
```

and last but not least HomeController

```
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public HomeController(OrderRepository repo)
    {
        _repository = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Data = _repository.FetchAll();
        return View();
    }
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that *Autofac* isn't able to find the assembly that host the `IRepository` type.

To resolive it,  you have to specify where to find the type in your *autofac* configuration. You can do it by specifying the assemblyname on the `service` attribute. The syntax is *namespace.typeName, assemblyName*

```xml
<autofac>
  <components>
    <component
      type="projectnamespace.Repositories.OrderRepository, assemblyName"
      service="projectnamespace.Repositories.IRepository, assemblyName" />
  </components>
</autofac>
```

In your case, it seems that the *assemblyName* is *projectName*

Comment: Thanks this fixed the error above. Now I get a new error:
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'projectnamespace.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:

Comment: Some more from the error stack: Cannot resolve parameter 'projectnamespace.Repositories.OrderRepository repo' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Go4Logistics.Tms.Portal.Web.Repositories.OrderRepository)'.

Comment: You have to register the `OrderRepository` in *Autofac*. I recommend reading some introduction article to understand key concept of dependency injection it will help you fixing further issue